# PHP No return from a function in another file

Tags: php, oop, wordpress, function, return

I have one file with a form, that includes another to process that form.  The file with the form calls a function in the included file to write data to the database, and then I return an $insert_id from that post so I can reference it in the output.

For example, when you fill out the form on the page, the data is sent to the db from a separate file, then I want to reference the ID it was given in the original file that I called the function from.

A snippet of the file with the form that includes the db process file:

```
if (isset($_POST['EC_doPost']))
{
    $statusPost = $_POST['EC_statusPost'];

    echo "HERE: " . $this->addEvent($title, $location, $linkout, $attendees, $description, $startDate, $startTime, $endDate, $endTime, $accessLevel, $postID) . "There.";

    $data = array
    (
        'post_content' => $output . "TESTING THIS: " . $event_id,
        'post_title' => $title,
        'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'post_category' => $wpdb->escape($this->blog_post_author),
        'post_status' => $statusPost,
        'post_author' => $wpdb->escape($this->blog_post_author),
    );
}
```

And here is s the function (in the included file) that should return the insert_id:

```
function addEvent($title, $location, $linkout, $attendees, $description, $startDate, $startTime, $endDate, $endTime, $accessLevel, $postID)
{
    $postID = is_null($postID) ? "NULL" : "'$postID'";
    $location = is_null($location) ? "NULL" : "'$location'";
    $description = is_null($description) ? "NULL" : "'$description'";
    $startDate = is_null($startDate) ? "NULL" : "'$startDate'";
    $endDate = is_null($endDate) ? "NULL" : "'$endDate'";
    $linkout = is_null($linkout) ? "NULL" : "'$linkout'";
    $attendees = is_null($attendees) ? "NULL" : "'$attendees'";
    $startTime = is_null($startTime) ? "NULL" : "'$startTime'";
    $accessLevel = is_null($accessLevel) ? "NULL" : "'$accessLevel'";
    $endTime = is_null($endTime) ? "NULL" : "'$endTime'";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `$this->mainTable` (`id`, `eventTitle`, `eventDescription`, `eventLocation`, `eventLinkout`, `eventAttendees`,`eventStartDate`, `eventStartTime`, `eventEndDate`, `eventEndTime`, `accessLevel`, `postID`) VALUES (NULL , '$title', $description, $location, $linkout, $attendees, $startDate, $startTime, $endDate, $endTime , $accessLevel, $postID);";

    $this->db->query($sql);

    $landingpage = "'http://www.google.com'";
    $status = "'1'";
    $title = "'".$title."'";
    $addedon = "'".date("Y-m-d")."'";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `$this->eventrTable` (`name`, `description`, `event_date`, `maximum_attendees`, `added_on`, `status`, `landing_page`) VALUES ($title, $description, $startDate, $attendees, $addedon, $status, $landingpage);"; 

    $this->db->query($sql);
    $event_id = $this->db->insert_id;

    return $event_id;
}
```

What I am trying to do is make two Wordpress plugins work together, but it's not going so well just yet.  If I make the included file with the function echo the variable, it works, but then I can't get it to work in the original file...

I'm sure it's something dumb, but I'm stumped.

Comment: @zombat I tried the revision you supplied, removing the $, but that resulted in a syntax error.  Maybe I'm overlooking something?

Comment: Oi, concatenating SQL queries together. You can write WP plugins without writing code like the WP devs. Use prepared statements!

Comment: @Lucas_Oman I'm not sure what you mean.  I'm primarily a designer, that dabbles in code more often than he should...

Comment: fixed code syntax for better readability

Comment: @KeepingYouAwake - oh, I didn't provide a revision of your code.  I just edited the question so the code formatting would show properly near the end.

Answer (score 0):

The addEvent() function is not returning the $event_id;

You should have something like this:

```
function addEvent(/*...*/)
{
    // ...

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `$this->eventrTable` ("
      ."`name`, `description`, `event_date`, `maximum_attendees`, `added_on`, `status`, `landing_page`) "
      ."VALUES ($title, $description, $startDate, $attendees, $addedon, $status, $landingpage);";

    $this->db->query($sql);
    $event_id = $this->db->insert_id;

    return $event_id;
}
```

Try doing the following:

```
var_dump($this->db->query($sql));
var_dump($event_id);
```

And post the output.

Comment: That's what I do have.  It's not working and I don't understand why...  See above.  Sorry, I did just edit the code to remove some comments that were disrupting the code display here.

Comment: Then I don't understand exactly what your problem is, maybe if you posted the whole file I could easily spot the problem.

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with your query, check my answer and post the output.

Comment: outputs shown respectively below:

var_dump($this->db->query($sql));
var_dump($event_id)

int(1)
int(23)

Comment: @KeepingYouAwake: what is the output for echo "HERE: " . $this->addEvent(...) . "There.";?

Comment: @eyze  The output for that line is "HERE: There.". It does complete the function of adding the entry to the database but doesn't return anything from that function, even if I set the return to a defined test string like return "CHEESE";.

Yes, it is inside a class called "EC_Management", then within the function "display()" of that class.

Comment: Weird, right?  I am seeing the results of the echo, except for the output of the function, but the function does run.  If I echo from the function, it outputs to the screen, but if I return a var from the function, no good.

Comment: Bummer...  Would it help to email you the files, or is there perhaps a way to bring more attention to this question?  I'm stuck, but in a way that seems like something odd is going wrong.

Comment: Try editing your question to provide more detail about the problem and other files, if you still don't get any solutions you can start up a bounty (but I think you need to have 100 reputation points to open one).